# Call WCF via another WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a situation where I would like to make a WCF call as another call is coming in.

```
Site1 request--> Site2
Site2 request --> Site3
Site2 <-- Site3 response
Site1 <-- Site2 response
```

The problem I am having is that when Site2 tries to send a message to Site3 while Site1 is sending to Site2; Site2 says it cannot find Site3.

The actual error message is:

```
Could not find endpoint element with name 'Endpoint_IEchoService' and contract 
'FakeCompany.API.Services.Contract.IEchoService' in the ServiceModel client 
configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found 
for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be 
found in the client element.
```

Each site is the same configuration and code base. The client, proxy and server are all in the same project. The apps are clones calling each other. It is one website with multiple address bindings. Other regular calls between the sites work fine until I try a call within a call.

As you can probably guess from the contact name, not much in the complex way is happening in my echo service. Single echo calls between the sites work. My problem is when i make a cascade call on the service side to another site.

I am wondering if this is not allowed or if a configuration setting change is required.

### Some code and config.

*Endpoint addresses are changed at runtime.*
*If you see something "funky", it is because the client, proxy and service inherit from generic base classes.*

**//-- ServiceModel Client**

```xml
<endpoint address="http://FakeCompany.unittest/Services/EchoService.svc"
 binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
 contract="FakeCompany.API.Services.Contract.IEchoService" name="Endpoint_IEchoService">
    <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="host/mikev-ws" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

**//-- Bindings**

```xml
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBinding" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" 
                 sendTimeout="00:05:00">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**//-- Behaviours**

```xml
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**//-- Services**

```
<service name="FakeCompany.API.Services.Service.EchoService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FakeCompany.API.Services.Contract.IEchoService" bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding" />
</service>
```

**//-- TEST**

```
[Test]
public void CascadeMessage()
{
    //-- TEST: That a wcf call can occur within another wcf call.

    //-- ARRANGE
    DTO_Echo_Cascade_Request request = new DTO_Echo_Cascade_Request(unit1, unit2);
    request.NextCall = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};", unit3, unit4, unit5);


    //-- ACT
    var response = EchoAgent.Cascade(request);

    //-- ASSERT
    Assert.AreEqual("TBA", response.Response);
}
```

**//-- AGENT**

```
internal static DTO_Echo_Response Cascade(DTO_Echo_Cascade_Request request)
{
    DTO_Echo_Response response;
    using (EchoServiceClient serviceClient = new EchoServiceClient(request))
    {
        response = serviceClient.Cascade(request);
    }

    return response;
}
```

**//-- CLIENT**

```
public DTO_Echo_Response Cascade(DTO_Echo_Cascade_Request request)
{
    return Process(() => Proxy.Cascade(request));
}
```

CONTRACT, DTO, PROXY are omitted.

**//-- SERVICE**

```
public DTO_Echo_Response Cascade(DTO_Echo_Cascade_Request request)
{
    DTO_Echo_Response response = new DTO_Echo_Response();

    response.Response += string.Format("Hello from {0};", request.TargetAddress);

    if (request.NextCall.NotNullOrEmpty())
    {
        var split = request.NextCall.Split(new [] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (split.GetUpperBound(0) > 0)
        {
            DTO_Echo_Cascade_Request nextRequest = new DTO_Echo_Cascade_Request(request.TargetAddress, split[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < split.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                nextRequest.NextCall += split[i] + ";";
            }
            response.Response += EchoAgent.Cascade(nextRequest).Response;
        }

    }

    return response;
}
```

***The exception occurs on the following line***

```
response.Response += EchoAgent.Cascade(nextRequest).Response;
```

Comment: Have you tested that Site 2 is able to communicate with Site 3 without Site 1 involved? Just to make sure you have Site 3 services set up correctly.

Comment: yes, each site is using the same code base and website app. Bindings of unit1 through to 5 are to the same IIS web app.

Comment: Could you post site 2 and site 3 configuration file

Comment: they are exactly the same as what i have posted above. This is because these sites use the same code base and website. Clones calling each other. I change the endpoint url dynamically. Other wcf calls work fine, just the call within a call does not.

Comment: Two things to note in your code.  The first is that the error message says it can't find AAAAAAAA.API.Services.Contract.IEchoService and the .config file has aaaaa.API.Services.Contract.IEchoService.  These two need to match and the match is case sensitive.  Another thing is that in your Agent you pass request as a parameter to your constructor, new EchoServiceClient(request).  Default service references don't take the request as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: i added AAAAAAA into the post to manually to hide the company name. In code they match. i will update my post. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: It looks pretty clear that Your test project has proper client configuration while your proxy service does not.

Comment: The client, proxy and server are in the same project and all have access to the same config files. updated post